# Credit Card Preauthorization's

Tags: api, validation, docusignapi, authorize.net, credit-card

I have a Business Pro Plan and if it is possible I would like to be able to have credit cards preauthorized for the amount of our quote and ensure that the card is valid when the owner of the card submits the information through DocuSign.

Comment: You mean for billing payments to DocuSign? I don't think this is a valid question for here.
If you mean using the DocuSign payment feature for customers - that is a valid question, but you would have to ask the payment providers, DocuSign works with them, and not directly deals with credit cards.

Comment: I do mean using the DocuSign payment feature for customers - and I have reached out to Authorize.Net and they told me that I need DocuSign to assit with getting the code setup.

Comment: hmmm, ok, I have never heard of this, I'll check and see if I can get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will require that you use APIs directly from payment providers. The DocuSign payment gateway doesn't have this capability directly. You can save credit cards for future use (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/save-payment-method) but that doesn't pre-authorize them until you charge them.

If Authorize.Net told you to contact DocuSign, then contact them again and don't mention DocuSign. They assume DocuSign code can be changed by you to make the calls you need, but that's not the case. You'll have to work with their APIs directly.